# what is the most lightweight way to make an async service call in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

What is the most lightweight way to make an async service call? My manager doesn't want to use jquery by default since it's fairly large at 80k. The async call must work within ie8. How hard is this to do in plain js? Or is there a subset of jquery or some other proven small specialized js lib that would be a good fit for what I'm looking for?

Comment: Take a look at [reqwest](https://github.com/ded/reqwest).

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly simple. You can use this example code here, but mind you. It does not scale! Asynchronous programming gets very complex, very quickly. If you have 2 or 3 asynchronous calls that intermingle (interfere at the data level on the server) you'll better think twice about what you are doing.

You may want to have an asynchronous job queue on the client so that calls are still asynchronous but executed in order. This is best done with promises.

This is an example AJAX call:

```
function send(data, callback)
{
  var xhr;

  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200)
    {
        callback(xhr.responseText);
    }
  };

  xhr.open("GET", "http://..../route/to/your/service/port", true);
  xhr.send();
}
```

Use it by passing on the callback function, like this:

```
send({ "hello": "world" }, function (response) {
  document.getElementById("response").innerText = response;
});
```

Comment: How about `callback.apply(this, arguments)` to pass whatever OP wants, :) and checking if type of callback is a function?

Comment: simpler is better. if this is just his code callback will be a function (why would he hurt himself?). if it's framework code that others consume then yes, better do all the necessary checks.

Comment: @pid thanks for the sample code and warning about scalability. here's the main use case: I'm developing a js framework component to display alerts. this component will call an alerts service on page load to check for any new notifications. different devs will add a ref to this js component on their websites. so this service will run asyncronously and independently once per page load. therefore, complexity and scalability shouldn't be a concern with the use of native xhr right?

Comment: Why use AJAX if you can deploy the alerts directly in the page on load? Remember you can't cross site boundaries (the service must be reached on the same URL). Apart from that you shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I have use [tinyxhr](https://github.com/cslarson/tinyxhr) in cases like that, give it a try (I'm not the author!)

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple plain javascript get request like this?

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/my/url', true);

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
      // Success!
      var resp = this.responseText;
    } else {
      // Error :(
    }
  }
};

request.send();
request = null;
```

Source: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#request

Comment: I was just looking at this, it requires IE9+; that's the case. :)

Comment: @AdamAzad No, it does not. I showed you the IE8+ Version. On the site you may select what (ie)-browser you need to support at least and this is the IE8-Version.

Answer (score 0):

There are many JavaScript micro libraries dedicated to XHR functionality, but if you are used to jQuery and like it, you can simply create your own build and exclude other modules that you don't need (this will of course reduce its size considerably):

https://github.com/jquery/jquery#modules

Also, you can use this site for building your own custom version:

http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/

The Gzipped result for you would be around 17Kb.

Comment: I think his boss said no jquery.

Comment: @pid -- The reason was due to its size though. My point was if he excluded unneeded modules that would no longer be an issue.

Comment: I don't know, I just upvoted to compensate. I don't want you to think that was me, because it wasn't me!

Comment: I agree generally speaking. 17KB are not much. On the other hand... 320 bytes of ASCII text are even less ;)

Comment: WOW it looks like someone downvoted everything, question and all answers, mine too :) We have a hater here... HAHAH

Comment: Fixed it by upvoting all!

Comment: @pid -- I guess so...someone didn't like the topic :) I don't have a comprehensive list of what jQuery ajax module will give you but I suspect it would provide some useful things such as IE fixes, etc